# Why does an NSArray of NSStrings work as a key for NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I'm not entirely clear on why or how this works.

I need to store a pair of identifiers (separately, so they can't be concatenated together) that map to an object. Originally, I was using a top level NSMutableDictionary instance for this, with nested NSMutableDictionary objects underneath that. To retrieve the value of an identifier pair, I could then call:

```
[[myTopLevelDictionary objectForKey:key1] objectForKey:key2]
```

And this would work suitably well, even though keeping track of the nested NSMutableDictionary instances requires a bit of extra work.

Yesterday, I was wondering if there was any way to use a pair of NSString objects as a key directly. So I tried creating an NSArray instance with two NSString objects and using that as the key instead, and it worked:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *key = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil];

[dict setObject:@"foobar" forKey:key];

NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:key]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil];

// Even this seems to work?
NSMutableArray *key2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
[key2 removeLastObject];

NSLog(@"%@", key2);
```

All three cases will successfully print "foobar". If I change the order of the NSString objects within the array, then the dictionary will return nil instead. If I add or remove NSString objects, again, the dictionary will correctly return nil. Only an NSArray object with the correct NSString objects containing the correct contents in the correct order seems to retrieve the appropriate value.

My question is... Why does this work, and how?

I know that hashing has something to do with it, but sending hash to an NSArray object just seems to return the object count, so I can't imagine that has much to do with it. Then I figured maybe NSDictionary was trying to get the NSArray's description and using that as a string based key, but I'm not sure how to test this theory since NSString's hash isn't the same as NSArray's hash (so I can't just use a NSString key that replicates the output of `[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil] description]`).

Don't get me wrong, it'd be great if I could use NSArray/NSString/NSMutableDictionary like this, I just want to make sure that things are working the way I think they are and that this isn't some kind of bizarre undefined behaviour or something.

Comment: `NSArray` implements deep equality: it sends `isEqual:` to each of the elements, comparing them to the elements of the other array. If each element from `self` equals the element at the corresponding position in the second array, it returns `YES`, else (or if the two arrays' counts aren't the same) it returns `NO`. Hashing is consistent with this behavior (equal arrays have necessarily equal hashes), and also `NSArray` is copiable, so there's no reason why an array of strings wouldn't work as a key.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't rely on it, particularly if every one of your keys is going to have the same hash value (array count).  That's potentially going to give you a badly unbalanced set of buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever "key" you use for a key/value input to a dictionary will be hashed and used as the real key internally. You have to be very careful when using an Array as the key because it you make ANY modification to it, its hash will change and therefore you won't be able to access the value anymore.

To answer your question, it works because the key (NSArray) can be hashed. How does it work: because the stored "key" is the hash of the NSArray, not the array itself (for performances and storage size reasons).
When you use an NSString as a key, it does the same and store the hash of the string internally.